# How can I get Bisection Method to print out all roots of a polynomial up to 5 exponents

Tags: java

I am doing a bisection method program where you input the coefficients up to the power of 5 and I find every root of the polynomial. My code only prints out the first root of the polynomial. How do I make it keep looking for other roots? Here is my code

```
public void bisectionMethod(double a, double b) {
        double average;
        double yOfC;
        double [] roots;
        int size = 1;
        while (size <= 5) {
            average = (a + b) / 2;
            yOfC = calculateY(average);
            if (Math.abs(yOfC) < 0.001) {
                System.out.println(average);
                size++;
            } else if (yOfC * calculateY(a) > 0) {
                a = average;
            } else {
                b = average;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my output

```
-0.9999990463256836
-0.9999990463256836
-0.9999990463256836
-0.9999990463256836
-0.9999990463256836
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a mathematical rather than a programming question (either that, or it's too broad because there are many ways to implement a mathematical solver in code). You may want to try http://math.stackexchange.com/ (read their help center first)

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a mathematical problem than a programming question.

Given two points in a continuous function *f*, you are guaranteed to find a root between points *a* and *b* if *f(a)*f(b)<0* (i.e. one value is positive and the other negative). However, this only guarantees one root.

To find another root, if it exists, a different interval must be chosen. However, you will not know until you calculate the root whether this new interval yields a new root. If interested in other root-finding algorithms I would suggest you read about them [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm).